# Python Run Code When Thread Finishes

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am currently writing a simple file server using Python and the Socket library. I have most of it finished, and now I'm writing a way to push an update to the server. Here's what I expect it to do:

1. Client Should Send New Python File To Server
2. Server Deletes File Previous Python File
3. Server Downloads Python File
4. Server Runs New Code
5. Server With Old Code Quits

As of right now, my program can do 1-3, but it still cannot run the new code and quit the program. Since the server program is about 100 lines long, [here's a link to the pastebin with the code](https://pastebin.com/WCwwRk6C). If you want to use the uploader too, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/xqnsPg6N).

Looking at my code, the problem either lies in my update code:

```
class updServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self,s):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.s = s
    def run(self):
        os.remove(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        fn = self.s.recv(2048)
        with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
            still_data = True
            while still_data:
                data = self.s.recv(2048)
                if not data:
                    still_data = False
                if data == '':
                    still_data = False
                f.write(data)
                f.flush()
                os.fsync(f.fileno())
        f.close()
        global name_of_file
        name_of_file = fn
        return None
```

Or in the way that I'm trying to run the new program under it:

```
elif file_name_sent == b'to update server':
        new_t = updServer(conn)
        threads.append(new_t)
        new_t.start()
        global name_of_file
        execfile(name_of_file)
        os._exit(0)
```

Note: I have also tried to use os.command and subprocess.call, and I also know that python is on my PATH. Instructions for the uploader are [here](https://pastebin.com/hrw196tc) if you want them.